# django query with prefetch_related

Tags: django

I am struggling to get at the data I need from a prefetch-related query.

I have a table of events (the calendar table), a table of members and an attendee table which links the two.

My models look like:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, verbose_name ='e-mail')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    membershipnum = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Attendee(models.Model):
    memberid = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.SET(0), related_name="attendingmembers")
    calendarid = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, on_delete=models.SET(0))
    attended =  models.BooleanField(default=0)
    paid =  models.BooleanField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'attendee'
```

For a particular event I want a list of attending members with the attended and paid fields from the attendee table.

In my view I have

```
attendees = Member.objects.filter(attendingmembers__calendarid_id=id).prefetch_related('attendingmembers')
```

I am getting the right members, but I don't know if this is the best way to do it? And I can't figure out how to get at the attendee fields.

If I do

```
for thisone in attendees:
        print(thisone)
        print(thisone.attendingmembers)
```

I get the expected return from the first print, but the second just gives me
myapp.Attendee.None

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You still need `.all()` to get the list of items of your relation:

```
for this one in attendees:
    print(thisone.attendingmembers.all())
```

Btw, do you wish to get all `attendingmembers` or only the ones with the right `calendar_id` ?

```
attendees = Member.objects.filter(attendingmembers__calendar_id=id).prefetch_related('attendingmembers')
# return all Members having at least one attendingmember with calendar_id=id, and prefetch all of their attendingmembers

attendees = Member.objects.filter(attendingmembers__calendar_id=id).prefetch_related(Prefetch('attendingmembers', queryset=Attendee.objects.filter(calendar_id=id)))
# return all Members  having at least one attendingmember with calendar_id=id, and prefetch their attendingmembers matching the filter
```

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects]) shows you how to use the `to_attr` argument in the Prefetch objects  ;)

Comment: All I really need is SELECT member.firstname, member.lastname, attendee.attended,attendee.paid FROM attendee LEFT JOIN member ON member.id = memberid_id WHERE calendarid_id = 176;
Is the Prefetch really necessary?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot filter on a `.select_related`.
Here, you want to filter the related objects, thus I think you'll need the `Prefetch`.
Again, [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) should help there.